# Plotly Go Plot not displaying properly on Dash and on Datapane

Tags: python, plot, plotly-dash, datapane

I am trying to plot on Dash and Datapane a simple interactive time series where certain time periods are indicated by the background being a certain color. Here is my MWE:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


t = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='M')
y = [1,2,3,2,1]

fig5 = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=t, y=y, mode='markers'))
fig5.add_vrect(
    x0=np.datetime64(datetime.date(2018,2,1)), x1=np.datetime64(datetime.date(2018,3,1)),
    fillcolor="LightSalmon", opacity=0.5,
    layer="above", line_width=0,
    )
fig5.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(

        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)
fig5.show()
```

My Jupyter notebook displays the plot just the way I expected it would:
[image]

But when I display it locally on Dash, the background height gets all messed up and it looks like this:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig5)]),
    html.Div([
        html.P('Some Statistic Here:')
    ])
])

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

[image]

When I try it in Datapane, I have the same issue:

```
import datapane as dp

dp.Report("## This shouldn't take this long",
    dp.Plot(fig5, caption="Why is this so hard?")
).save(path='report.html', open=True)
```

[image]

With my actual data, it looks even worse. This is what it looks like in my Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

This is what it looks like both in Dash and Datapane. I guess the vertical bars are so short that they can't even be seen in the plot and the slider also doesn't show any datapoints. I have tried `layer = above` and `layer = below` but it doesn't make any difference.

[image]

Comment: I ran my environment in jupyterLab, combining your Notebook code and Dash code. It successfully displays the same output as the Notebook. I don't have the code, and there may be an issue in your environment. the modules required by dash are below, so you may need to check if they are up to date. `Flask, dash-table, flask-compress, dash-html-components, dash-renderer, plotly, dash-core-components, future`

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you for taking the time to test it and comment. Lemme check my environment.

Comment: is it solved now? @Amatya